# Why doesn't standard helper for delete_model_path exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

For example, if I have a model `Item`, and I define resourceful routes for it, I must include `:delete` action as a member by hand, why is that?

Example:

```
# .../config/routes.rb

resources :items do
  member { get :delete }
end
```

I need `:delete` action to display a confirmation dialog to users. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Or am I doing it right and it is the best practice?

Comment: FYI, you should never use `GET` for delete/destroy actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because **by default** you're supposed to display the confirmation dialog with client-side JS, as described by @SergioTulentsev. Having a separate page for "delete confirmation" **is just uncommon** and therefore not default.

Yes, you may have noticed the patterns in some actions: `new` is an "interfacing stub" for `create`, just as `edit` is for `update`, they don't do anything by default, they only send you the interface to make an actual action.

An action itself, however, is posting with the appropriate HTTP verb (`POST`, `DELETE`, etc.) to a resource's path, and that's pretty much what everyone's suggesting. However, it's important to know that **links can only do `GET`** (forms can do the rest). To make a link issue `DELETE`, you have to augment it with JavaScript using Rails' helpers. That's what everyone's suggesting. And this won't work if JavaScript turns out to be disabled (if you care about that ridiculously low percentage of human users).

What you're about to do is the same "interfacing stub" for `destroy`. You can call it `delete` and have the route named accordingly. *It's just not common,* that's all.

Still, if it **is** common to you, consider making a **route concern**, or even your own helper. I've seen the need for such in APIs that have little to no user interface, and as such don't need `new` or `edit` from default helpers.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you display confirmation dialogs by using unobtrusive js. Something like this

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', item_path(@item), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

This will generate a piece of JS that will intercept click on the link and display confirmation modal. If you choose to proceed, it will then send the form.

And yes, do not perform such dangerous actions via a GET request (unless you have valid reasons)

Comment: The get request is only for a confirmation dialog to show up, is it still dangerous? Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderLomia: and how the actual deletion happens?

Comment: @AlexanderLomia: if you have some highly customized confirmation dialog, that has to appear at its own page, then that's what you have: an intermediate page. It's not one of restful routes and, as such, is not generated. Not sure why you're surprised by it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard action for deleting objects is called `destroy`, and is one of the seven routes defined by `resources :items`.

You can call it in your example with `link_to "Delete", item_path(@item), method: :delete`.

You should never perform destructive actions with a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

> I must include :delete action as a member by hand

No, you don't need to.

Look up [Rails' guide on *resourceful* routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) for more info:

[image]

As mentioned in the other answers, you have to invoke the `destroy` path helper using the following:

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", items_destroy_path(@item), method: :delete %>
```

You also need to have [`Rails UJS`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) appended to your JS to get it to work.